# Reading delimited file and replacing variables with shell

Tags: bash, sh, zsh

I have a text file in the following format:

```
78 45 89 45
```

I would like to read the first two variables (here, 78 and 45) with bash script, perform some computations and replace the values with new variables computed.

Can someone throw light on this?

Comment: need to post also the calculations you want to perform and desired output ( with reference to the calculations )

Comment: Where is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

This is POSIX and should work in any Bourne-heritage shell:

```
while read first second rest; do
   first=$((first * 2))
   second=$((second + 42))
   printf '%s\n' "$first $second $rest"
done < input
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example (**Edit:** in `bash` only) to get you started, in which I add `12` to the first value and add `22` to the second value in each line.

```
$ cat /tmp/text.file
78 45 89 45
88 55 90 50
$ cat /tmp/comp.sh

while read line; do
        a=($line)
        a[0]=$(( a[0] + 12 ))
        a[1]=$(( a[1] + 22 ))
        echo "${a[@]}"
done < /tmp/text.file

$ bash /tmp/comp.sh
90 67 89 45
100 77 90 50
```

Comment: This doesn't work in `sh`, which doesn't support arrays.

Comment: Despite the tags, the user specifically mentions a `bash` script in the question.

Comment: `read -a a` would be a more direct way of setting the value of `a`.